# Hashtag in pinterest share description

Tags: html, pinterest

I'm trying to set up social sharing with pinterest on my page. It works fine, except hashtags don't seem to show up.

I quickly threw together a [jsfiddle with my code](http://jsfiddle.net/aLoLjkwd). As you can see I put a hashtag in the description, but when the box pops up for sharing it omits the tag altogether.

```
<a onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Share on Pinterest', 'width=640, height=536')" 
href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?
url=http://google.com&media=http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&description=this is a #hashtag" 
class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"> 
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/files/pinterest_e8e717fe-0b0d-4a38-8290-5c5beb871dd4.png?9971" width=22/></a>
```

Does anyone know how I can put a hashtag in the description and have it work? I tried using

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the # for URL - replace it with %23 and you'll get your desired result - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLoLjkwd/1/)

```
<a onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Share on Pinterest', 'width=640, height=536')" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://google.com&media=http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&description=this is a %23hashtag" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
   <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/files/pinterest_e8e717fe-0b0d-4a38-8290-5c5beb871dd4.png?9971" width=22/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing '#' with the HTML character for hashtag:

```
&#35;
```

Comment: After testing, that does not seem to work either. Sorry about that. I will keep digging.

Comment: I believe you will have to dynamically add the hashtag using JavaScript.